# Can't change defaultValue attribute of input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some onfocus/onblur handlers for a field that clears the default contents when focused, but only if the value equals the default value (so as to not remove any user input).

The field can also toggle between inputs. So rather than accepting a username, the user could click a button and it would accept an email address. This would require a different default value, such as "enter your email address". The actual property attribute `defaultValue` needs to be changed to allow my focus/blur handlers to work properly, using something like this:

```
$('input#ident-field').prop('defaultValue', 'enter your email address');
```

This doesn't seem to work because if you focus the field when it asks for an email address it doesn't clear it.

Comment: read about [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) :  It should be used when setting selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, or defaultSelected.

Comment: So not defaultValue? Either way, I've tried .attr() and .prop() and neither are working.

Comment: see my answer; if still you wants to go with jQuery then use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shoud use HTML 5 attribute  [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your email address" / >
```

Comment: You'll also want to add https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder to make it work in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the use of focus and blur functions:

```
$('input#ident-field').val("enter your email address");
// or $('input#ident-field').prop('defaultValue', 'enter your email address');
$('input#ident-field').focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
});
$('input#ident-field').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().trim() == "")
    {
        $(this).val("enter your email address");
    }
});
```